# PHP comparing times worked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating an HTML table that displays allocations of employees time in 2 different ways. The first way, is an ajax updated Queue that shows current employees where-abouts, which is completed.

The second type is a form where the user can enter a past "allocation". Now, because my business is 24/7 I decided to store all times as Date-Times in mysql, so I could get the difference of:

`2013-04-11 21:59:29` and `2013-04-12 01:52:29`

Here is the form that is being filled out:

```
 <form action="mafs.php" method="post" id="form1" name="form1" class="">     

                    <table id="tbl_past_allocation">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right" style="font-size:11px;">Employee Name</td>
                        <td ><input placeholder=" John Doe" style="width:100px; border-radius:10px;" type="text" name="peename" id="peename" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right" style="font-size:11px;">Home Department</td>
                        <td>          <select style="width:140px; border-radius:10px;" name="phomedept">

                <option value="select">Select Department</option></center>
                <option value="ADC/NFC Shipping Department">ADC/NFC Shipping Department</option>
                <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
                <option value="Receiving Department">Receiving Department</option>
                <option value="Cable">Cable Department</option>
                <option value="Department">CPM Department</option>
                <option value="Dispatch Clerk">Dispatch Clerk</option>
                </select></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right" style="font-size:11px;">Sent to Department</td>
                        <td>          <select style="width:140px; border-radius:10px;" name="psentdept">

                <option value="select">Select Department</option></center>
                <option value="ADC/NFC Shipping Department">ADC/NFC Shipping Department</option>
                <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
                <option value="BP Receiving Department">BP Receiving Department</option>
                <option value="Cable Department">Cable Department</option>
                <option value="CPM Department">CPM Department</option>
                <option value="Dispatch Clerk">Dispatch Clerk</option>
                <option value="Inventory Control Department">Inventory Control Department</option>
                <option value="IRM Shipping Department">IRM Shipping Department</option>
                <option value="Kitting Department">Kitting Department</option>
                <option value="Lead">Lead</option>
                <option value="LSC Receiving Department">LSC Receiving Department</option>
                <option value="LSC Shipping Department">LSC Shipping Department</option>
                <option value="NAR E&O Department">NAR E & O Department</option>
                <option value="Non-Conformance Department">Non-Conformance Department</option>
                <option value="Performance Department">Performance Department</option>
                <option value="Quality Auditors">Quality Auditors</option>
                <option value="Quality Department">Quality Department</option>
                <option value="Returns Department">Returns Department</option>
                <option value="Software Department">Software Department</option>
                <option value="Special Ops Team">Special Ops Team</option>
                <option value="Supervisors">Supervisors</option>
                <option value="Training/Meetings/Projects">Training/Meetings/Projects</option>

                </select></td>
                      </tr>

                       <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right" style="font-size:11px;">Time Sent</td>
                    <td ><input placeholder=" mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss" style="width:140px; border-radius:10px;" type="text" name="ptimesent" id="ptimesent" /></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right" style="font-size:11px;">Time Returned</td>
             <td ><input placeholder=" mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss" style="width:140px; border-radius:10px;" type="text" name="ptimereturned" id="ptimereturn" /></td>
                      </tr>


                    </table>
                    <!--tbl_equipment_details closed-->
                            <div>
         <input class="button" value="Submit Record" name="pastadd" type="submit" style="width:300px; cursor:pointer; margin-top:5px;">
                            </div>  
                            </form>
```

I'm having trouble with a few different things regarding this.

1. First of all, I'm curious what format would work best for storing this type of time.
2. What would be the easiest on the user entering this information in the form? 4 separate inputs and then concatenating them together? or 2 and just require them to enter it in the specified format?

Comment: Does your application need to be concerned with different time zones?

Comment: Use a date picker & a time picker so that your user won't face much trouble entering the info. jQuery UI provide the datepicker, as for time picker, I'm sure there's a lot on the internet.

Comment: timezone is not a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the separate inputs are the most user-friendly and the least error-prone, since they're all select boxes.  Then concat the values together and, for me personally, convert them to a timestamp. Timestamps are also 24/7 compatible. :)

I always use a unix timestamp to save my gmt dates.  Then to compare them it's simple math.

```
<?php

//
// Some comparison stuff
//

// 1 day = 86400 seconds
// mktime returns a unix timestamp.
$date1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2013); // Jan. 1st, 2013
$date2 = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 15, 2013); // Jan. 15th, 2013

// Get the difference
$diff = ($date2 / 86400) - ($date1 / 86400); // 14

echo $diff;

//
// Some conversion stuff
//
// Use mktime([$hour, $min, $sec, $mon, $day, $year]) if you have 
// a specific date you want converted into a timestamp, else use 
// time(), which is the current timestamp.
//
// Convert to human readable format
// 
$datetime = date("H:i:sa - M jS, Y", $timestamp); // $timestamp optional

echo $datetime; // e.g. 4:23:46pm - Jan 1st, 2013

?>
```

P.S. Don't confuse my use of a "unix" timestamp with the mysql datatype TIMESTAMP.  A unix timestamp is the number of seconds (as an integer) which have elapsed since Jan 1st, 1970 (? I believe ?).

// MySQL TIMESTAMP data type.

```
The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts.   
TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
```

Please don't hesitate to correct me if I have made any incorrect assumptions.
Thanks!

Comment: I'll give this a go in just a bit. Thank you for your response.

Comment: This also allows you to set your fields which hold the timestamp to integer types, which the default "int" uses half the storage size, 4 bytes compared to 8 for datetime.

Comment: Although a TIMESTAMP data type is only 4 bytes as well, it really comes down to programmer preference/comparison difficulty.